# Stckoverflow says BAD REQUEST on PHP

Tags: php, curl

I  have this `cURL` code in php.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80); //ignore explicit setting of port 80
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

The contents of `HTTPHEADER` are  ;

```
Proxy-Connection: Close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1017.2 Safari/535.19
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __qca=blabla
Connection: Close
```

Each of them individual items in the array `$v`.

When I upload the file on my host and run the code, what I get is :

> **400 Bad request**
>
> Your browser sent an invalid request.

But when I run it on my system using command line PHP, what I get is this and the full page.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Date: Sat, 03 Mar 2012 21:50:17 GMT
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: buncha cokkies; path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 22151
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

.

**It's not only on stackoverflow, this happens, it happens also on 4shared, but works on google and others.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You know there's an [API for StackOverflow](http://api.stackoverflow.com/), right? There's no reason to query pages like that.

Comment: It is not an `API` thing I'm doing. That's why the line in bold is there.

Comment: I understand it doesn't solve your problem, but if you're going to connect to SO (or any site) you should use their API if they have one whenever possible.

Comment: Could you post the **full** `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` output (including request data) from the case where it goes wrong (on your web server)? A 400 error means there's something wrong with the request, so this is pretty important information.

Comment: @AnotherCode The thing is that it is stackoverflow, 4shared that are returning these responses, so the curl request actually goes through. I'd post more details now.

Answer (score 1):

Your empty CURLOPT_ENCODING argument is causing the issue. If you don't want gzip/deflate, simply omit the header.

I also see you're defining encoding both in your curl_setopt() and in the `HTTP_HEADER` array. 
You should use native `curl_setopt()` commands when possible. `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` is one you can move out of your `HTTP_HEADER` array.

But as Andrew Marshall mentioned, screen-scraping isn't something you should be doing; especially since they have an API.

**EDIT**

Here's the sample script I'm using:

```
<?php

$v = Array(
    'Proxy-Connection: Close',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1017.2 Safari/535.19',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Cookie: __qca=blabla',
    'Connection: Close'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java"));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80); //ignore explicit setting of port 80
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Now I'm running this via command-line, but the net effect is the same. I removed the Accept-Encoding in the `$v` array simply so I could get un-compressed output.

The one thing we haven't established is your PHP and libcurl versions. For me, this is PHP 5.3.2 with libcurl 7.12.1. This can be important. You can find your libcurl version either by `php -i | grep -i curl` on the command line, or `phpinfo()` via a web-based script on your server.

Comment: I wonder why an empty `CURLOPT_ENCODING` would cause problems, since [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says an empty string will send a list of supported encodings? I personally use an empty encoding setting all the time in my projects.

Comment: It is not causing the issue. I have tried it with and without encodings. It still returns the same thing.

Comment: @AnotherCode - Dunno. Re-created OP's script and got "* Error while processing content unencoding. incorrect header check" when CURLOPT_ENCODING was set to the empty string. Otherwise I was able to get it working just fine.

Comment: @Blank - Just to be certain, your $v array has one entry per array member, and isn't an associative array, right? i.e. $v = Array('Proxy-Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: Mozilla..', 'Accept: text/html...', ...); yes? I know you said something to that effect, but it wasn't really clear from your code example.

Comment: @Blank, please check my edit and see if our script matches, and if you can, answer the question re: php and libcurl versions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some header is breaking the expected request pattern on some sites. The easiest way to fix this would be to remove the headers one by one and test.

I think it should be the encoding one.

Comment: It might be caused by any other headers, try those

Comment: But it works on my laptop with all those headers. But when I upload to my host I get bad request.

Comment: Does it work if you call the page from the browser on your laptop?

Comment: That's how I am even calling the page.

Answer (score -2):

It seems the "Host" header is missing:

```
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: The cURL library automatically includes this when using HTTP/1.1 (default).